# Angular Velocity About Instantaneous Axis of Rotation

Tags: classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, torque

If you consider a cone of half angle φ rolling without slipping on a plane with angular velocity Ω as shown in the figure. What would be the angular velocity about the Instantaneous Axis of rotation? And also about the axis of the cone?
My try at the solution:
Well first I found out that the Instantaneous Axis of rotation is the x axis and then and also the torque has to be provided by the friction alone as no other force is acting and finally I used torque equation as the cross product of vector(ω) and vector(L). But the answer given doesn't match my answer. The answer I got was Ωcosecφ and the textbook answer says Ωcotφ. Please help if I have gone wrong somewhere. [image: figure shows a cone of half angle φ]

Comment: the angular velocity about the instantaneous  axis of rotation is Ωcosφ and not Ω

Comment: @harsh somani who said it is Ω? And how is it cosφ?

Comment: I am sorry its Ω/cosφ

Comment: this video might help https://youtu.be/m4F6YXeJdvw start from 4:54 if you dont want to watch the complete video

Comment: Exactly if you solve you get cosec not sec